# PHP: About replacing part of the $_FILES information with a variable

Tags: php

Can I do this?

I do have this variable, taken from an html form:

```
$dni = $_FILES['dni'];
```

And I would like to use that variable like this:

```
$dni["tmp_name"];
```

Instead of this:

```
$_FILES["dni"]["tmp_name"];
```

I've tried that but it won't work and the error logs are silent (doesn't show anything). Is there a way to achieve that?

### UPDATE:

This is the actual implementation:

```
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$dni = $_FILES['dni'];

define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

function cargarDNI($archivo, $email) {
    $uploadDir = '/archivosAlumnos';
    $tmp_name = strip_tags($dni["tmp_name"]);
    $nombreOriginal = $dni["name"];
    $pathInfo = pathinfo(SITE_Root.$nombreOriginal);
    $extension = $pathInfo['extension'];
    $pattern = "/[^A-Za-z0-9]/";
    $nombreSanitizado = preg_replace($pattern, "", $nombreOriginal);
    $nombreFinal = strtolower($nombreSanitizado);
    $tipo = 'dni';
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, SITE_ROOT."$uploadDir/$email--$tipo--$nombreFinal.$extension");
};

cargarDNI($dni, $email);
```

Comment: The lines you've shown seem perfectly valid. May we see the part of your actual implementation?

Comment: I agree with @Siguza. You could try doing a print_r($_FILES); and a print_r($dni); to see what the arrays contain at each step, to help debug.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated the question, and I'll try printing out that. Bythe way, If I use $_FILES["dni"], instead of $dni it does work.

Comment: It's a scope issue. In php, variables declared outside a function are not visible within a function. `$_FILES` is a magic built in PHP array called a "super global" which means it is available everywhere (includes `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SESSION`...etc). However, your `$dni` variable, declared outside the function, isn't visible within the function where you are trying to use it. Since you are passing in `$dni` under the `$archivo` argument, inside your function, change `$dni` to `$archivo` and it will work.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn .. damn.. you ninja'd me - I just got there :) haha

Comment: @Alfie, make it an answer as that is correct. I just don't have the time to fully correct their code.

Comment: @Siguza `preg_replace` is global, there is no [preg_replace_all](https://php.net/preg_replace_all) (unlike `preg_match(_all)?`). There is however a `$limit` argument to limit the number of replacements.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn ok - thanks, have done :)

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn You're right! Than you! It works now!

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ugh, I derped. You're right, I confused the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Johnatan Kuhn first mentioned in the comments, the issue is to do with variable scope; variables defined outside of a function are not 'known/visible' inside that function.

Given that you are passing the array to your function already, there is no benefit in assigning it to a separate variable before you do. Simply passing `$_FILES['dni']` as the first parameter will do what you need:

Remove the second line: `$dni = $_FILES['dni'];`

And change your function call on the last line to: `cargarDNI($_FILES['dni'], $email);`

Then, inside the function itself, replace all references to `$dni` to your parameter `$archivo`. So, the line in the function that reads: `$nombreOriginal = $dni["name"];` should then be `$nombreOriginal = $archivo["name"];`

edit: also the line in the function: `$tmp_name = strip_tags($dni["tmp_name"]);`, change to: `$tmp_name = strip_tags($archivo["tmp_name"]);`